# Populating table after delete PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo

When the user logs in he will go to a page where there is a table, the table is populated fine with delete link on each line. If I click the delete link it will delete the record but when it refreshes the page the table would not load with this message.

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'host' (using password: NO)
Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in 
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Why would it let me populate the table the first time and then again It won't. Here is my delete code.

```
$id_actividades = $_GET['idactividades'];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM guaynabodb.actividades WHERE idactividades=:id_actividades");

$stmt -> bindParam(':id_actividades', $id_actividades);
     try{
      $stmt->execute();
     }
     catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage(),'Cannot delete',"\n";

      }
      header('Location: actividades.php');//To redirect
      exit;
```

This is the code of the page where I have the table. It loads after you login but If I delete one record it won't load.

```
  include('../includes/dbschema.php');
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM actividades");
          $stmt->execute();
     print " <h1 id=\"h2title\">Calendario de Actividades</h1><br/><br/>";//Print the title header

           echo "<table id=\"premiacionguaynabo\"> <tr> <th> No. </th> <th> Fecha </th> <th> Torneo </th> <th> Lugar </th> <th> Organizador </th> <th> Opciones </th> </tr>"; //The table and the headers are created  

             $tno = 0;

              $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

              foreach($result as $line){
                $tno = $tno + 1;
     $id = $line["idactividades"];
    print "<tr class=\"alt2\">"; 

    print "<td id=\"idtorneo\">  $tno  </td>";
    print "<td class=\"fechatorneo\"> " . $line['fecha_inicial'] . " al " . $line['fecha_final'] .  "</td>";
    print "<td> <a id=\"plinks\"  href=\"$picture\" rel=\"lightbox\" target=\"_top\" title=\"Flyer del Torneo\"> " . $line['ntorneo'] . " </a></td>";
    print "<td>" . $line['ltorneo'] . "</td>"; 
    print "<td>" . $line['otorneo'] . "</td>"; 

    print "<td id=\"idtorneo\"> <a id=\"udlinks\"  href=\"uactividades.php?idactividades=$id\">  Edit  </a>   <a id=\"udlinks\" onclick=\"return confirmDelete()\"  href=\"dactividades.php?idactividades=$id\">  Delete  </a></td>";
    print "</tr>"; 

        }

    print "</table>";
```

Comment: Obviously: your mysql username of password is incorrect (not set in this case).

Comment: No because the first time I load the table page it will grant me access.

Comment: And binding `:id` is not going to work, you need to bind :`table_id`

Comment: I rename it for posting it here, but I will put the one that I have in code.

Comment: Your error messages don't match your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message mention `mysql_query()` function which is absent in the code you posted.
So, either these functions are left in the code by accident or you just posting the wrong code.
Please read the error messages you have. They are quite informative.

Comment: I don't have those functions in my code. I remove all of them and changed to PDO. I'm going to read carefully my code again but there was nothing the last time I check.

Comment: I look closely to my code and I found that I was redirecting to a wrong page on my folder that did have old coding from mysql_query. I deleted the old page and changed the code in the new one to redirect to the correct one. Thanks.